# Android lock home key press

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I know it is not possible to lock/detect/disable the home key in Android device.

I am using the following code which shows "Complete action using" dialog:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

By checking on "Use by default for this application"and selecting my application, it becomes the home screen app for every time user presses "Home". Upto this it was OK but when user updates the application from market this setting is cleared.

How can I retain this setting even after application update from market?